# How to install SPFX (in site collection app catalog) to subsites automatically

Tags: spfx, app-catalog

Say I have a SPO site collection with a site app catalog.  And I have an app (a number of webparts) installed in the site collection app catalog.t I need these webparts installed/useable automatically on all subsites (new and old)

How in the wide world of sports can I do that?
Are apps deployed at top level site site collection app catalogs available to subsites by default?

**powershell not available (probably cant use pnp site templates)

**cant deploy to tenant app catalog

**powerautomate not available.

Any help greatly appreciated!
-Powell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting `skipFeatureDeployment` to `true` in your **package-solution.json** file.

This feature is normally used for tenant-scoped deployment and gives the administrator the option to make the solution available to all sites and subsites in the tenant. Since you're deploying from the site collection app catalog, hopefully with this enabled you will be given the option to make the solution available to the entire site (including all subsites).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I dismissed that as not an option.  It is certainly worth a try though!

Comment: Hey, just to round this out.
I added skipfeaturedeployment true, and it WORKED!
Had to make sure to check the box to deploy to all sites.   App was then available to all subsites without need to activate/install in each subsite.
Thank you again!